# Bootstrap 4: DropDown menu doesn't function EDIT: IN firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am practicing django frameworks. I Don't have much experience with front-end development But I've already work with bootstrap 4 and implement dropdown menu but I couldn't make this work.

I've already checked cdn and misspelling in classes but couldn't find the problem

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, \
    initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}Newspaper App{% endblock title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'article_new' %}">+ New</a></li>
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ user.username }}
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Change password</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        {% else %}
          <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Log In</a>
            <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
            Sign up</a>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content %}
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"\ integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4\
    YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/\
    JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All cdn are in order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"\ integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4\
YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/\
JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

EDIT: I mean dropdown menu inside if statement
EDIT: The problem was with firefox . It is working with google chrome

Comment: Which one you wnat to drop down?

Comment: I think you're trying to use drop down inside if statement.